# Laravel model belongs to relationship loading issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have two models, Box and BoxLocations. `Box` has a `hasMany` relation to `BoxLocations` and `BoxLocations` has a `belongsTo` relationship to `Box`.

`BoxLocations` also has an attribute that is appended to the model that required a single piece of information from the Box relation.

I have noticed that when calling `Box::with(['BoxLocations']->)all();` I see that the `BoxLocations` model is re-loading the Box relationship. This is happening for each `BoxLocation` (50 odd times)

Does laravel not track that the Box was already loaded from the initial `Box::with(['BoxLocations']->)all();` request and then pass this to the BelongsTo relationship?

I am trying to optimise a web system and when the taken attribute is loaded (annoyingly its required every time its loaded as well) its causing 50 odd hits to the database for the same Box model it has already loaded.

If laravel does not do this - is there a better way in which to achieve the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel uses [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) when you use the `with()` method.

> When accessing Eloquent relationships as properties, the relationship data is "lazy loaded". This means the relationship data is not actually loaded until you first access the property. However, Eloquent can "eager load" relationships at the time you query the parent model. Eager loading alleviates the N + 1 query problem.

So if you do this:

```
$boxes = Box::with('BoxLocations')->get();
```

It will load the relations already, but lets' say you do this:

```
$boxes = Box::all();

foreach($boxes as $box)
{
  echo box->boxlocation->name;
}
```

If you have 50 Boxes, this loop would run 51 queries.

But when you use the `with` method and eager load the relation, this loop will run only 2 queries.

You could also use [Lazy Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) and decide when you want to load the relationship

Comment: I have marked this answer as correct; however I found that laravel was still executing more queries than i needed via this method. I found it far better to write a DB query to get the fields I wanted in one DB call rather than let laravels relationships hit the database multiple times

Comment: Thank you, can you tell me how many queries it was executing using the relations? that could be a bug and  we could report it. Also, i would appreciate if you show the query you made

Comment: i cant remember the code now, but basically i had a manufacturer table with, say, 'Apple' in it and a devices table with a lot of apple products in it. When doing ```Devices::with('manufacturers')->get()``` you get a single query for each devices manufacturer. I think it should get the manufacturer for the first one, then cache it for the rest of them. However this is in legacy laravel 5.5 code.. so might not be an issue now.